# UploadFromFileAsync(string path) throw exception could not find your location

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I am using UploadFromFileAsync(@"E:\test.html"); when isend the path ,it is throw the exception colud not find location ,The file is exist in my path
Can any one help me

```
fileName = @"E:\\test.html"; 
cloudFile = fileDirectory.GetFileReference(fileName); // Upload a file to the share. 
await cloudFile.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName);
cloudFile.Metadata.Add("FileName", cloudFile.Name); 
cloudFile.Metadata.Add("Status", "1");
await cloudFile.SetMetadataAsync();
```

Comment: If it can't find the file, it can't find the file. Start by providing a code snippet, and where you're executing the code along with where the file is. Are you executing the code while the file is on your local PC?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the [FAQ] and [ask]. Then come back and edit your qeustion.

Comment: Maybe your test.html file has an another extension which you don't see in windows explorer?

Comment: fileName = @"E:\\test.html";
cloudFile = fileDirectory.GetFileReference(fileName);
 // Upload a file to the share.                        
await cloudFile.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName);                            cloudFile.Metadata.Add("FileName", cloudFile.Name);
cloudFile.Metadata.Add("Status", "1");
await cloudFile.SetMetadataAsync(); 

This is the code

Comment: Since you have tagged this with Azure I'm going to guess this code is running in Azure and it is a web application. If that is the case then your problem is that an Azure App Service is not going to be able to see your E: drive. It would be like me running this code on my machine and expecting to get your file. It is a common misconception to think because you are browsing the site on your machine that the code will act as if it is on your machine.

Comment: Is this a .net core web project?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a console project running in azure like webjobs, I dont' think you can upload the file from local system to azure storage. Because it's running in azure and don't know the local path.

If it's a .net core web project, like a mvc project, you can use `IFormFile`, which allow users select a file from local.

Sample code like below:

In the controller.cs(here, I create a ImagesController.cs):

```
    public class ImagesController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile file)
        {

            if (file == null || file.Length == 0) return Content("file not selected");
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("xx", "xxxx"), true);
            CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference("container_name");
            await blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            var blockblob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                await blockblob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
            }

            return View();
        }
}
```

Then in the view, like `Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<html>
<head>
    <title>upload files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-controller="Images" asp-action="Index" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.